# Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null In taking photo with Camera

Tags: java, android, camera

I Saw another questions about this problem but non of them helped.

In my app there two different ways for adding an image and displaying it inside an imageview. 1. Gallery - 2. Camera.

gallery way is working just fine.

But in Camera way (which I'm doing it with native android Camera) I have a confusing problem.

If I rotate my phone to portrait mode (so the portrait xml loads) and take the photo in portrait mode, it works fine.

If I rotate it to landscape and use use camera also in landscape, it works fine too.

now if my xml is in portrait and after going to camera I rotate it to landscape (to take a lansdcape photo) app crashes and gives me this Errors:

```
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.kpaxteam.babyalbum/com.tiktak.albums1.A2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2918)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2970)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:132)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1068)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4277)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:745)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:258)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at com.tiktak.babyalbum.Helper.pathgal(Helper.java:161)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at com.tiktak.babyalbum.Helper.resultpic(Helper.java:299)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at com.tiktak.albums1.A2.onActivityResult(A2.java:242)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4053)
05-08 21:34:22.974: E/AndroidRuntime(19000):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2914)
```

My Intent for taking photo:

```
                       Intent cameraIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                       cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);  
                       act.startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, int2);
```

My ActivityResult:

```
else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
 Helper line 299--->        String capturedImageFilePath = Helper.pathgal(act, mCapturedImageURI);
            bmp = Helper.decodeFile(capturedImageFilePath, act);
            if(bmp != null )
            {
                try {
                    Helper.showpic(act, id1, bmp);
                    settings = act.getSharedPreferences(st1, 0);
                    settings.edit().putString(st2, capturedImageFilePath).putInt(st3, View.VISIBLE).putInt(st4, View.GONE).commit();;
                    img1 = (ImageView) act.findViewById(id1);
                    img2 = (ImageView) act.findViewById(id2);
                    img1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    img2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                    Toast.makeText(act.getApplicationContext(), "Try Again",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            }
```

getting image file path code:

```
public static String pathgal(Activity act, Uri uri){

    String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

 Helper 161--->   Cursor cursor = act.getContentResolver().query(uri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();

    return filePath;
    }
    return null;

}
```

any idea?

Comment: If you debug, what are the values of assorted variables (`uri`, `filePathColumn`, etc) right before the line throwing the exception?

Comment: filePathColumn is the string in 2 line above Cursor, and the uri is that uri which i'm using in cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Should've Just add android:configChanges="orientation" in my manifest to activities.

Thanks everyvone.

Comment: Still crashes for me every time I start the camera, rotate it and keep it rotated until I store the picture and return the thumbnail.

Comment: @G_V I think you should add 'android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"' too.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

I had same problem resolved by it`

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

        timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        name=mode+"_"+img_type+"_"+timeStamp+".jpeg";
        output = new File(dir,name);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,Uri.fromFile(output));
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1);


    }
```

and in onActivityResult use output.getAbsolutePath()(where output is the file which we used to create uri to pass in camera intent)) to get that image

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

String IMAGE_URL=output.getAbsolutePath();

            }
```

Comment: Still nulls out every time my camera orientation doesn't match the underlying activity.